# Designing a full dynamic cms with user defined menus and input form templates using php

Tags: php, content-management-system, template-engine

I am going to make a cms which gives the administrator the opportunity to define menus and their contents. for the menus' contents i am going to design a template system in which the admin can define input form fields and their types (text, select, radio, checkbox,...) for the content.

I want to know how do u design this system. Do u save your templates in xml format or other formats? Do u save these templates in file or database? And do u make database tables for storing these templates' inserted data?

And at last do u know any cms which uses this system to generate input forms dynamically?

By the way i am using php and zend framework also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is way too broad, and you're asking others for opinion, which normally is not helpful with broad questions. If you're more specific with your questions, this might help you to actually solve things.

Comment: +1 hakre. You should define your question better, asking for specifics rather that something pretty general. Regardless, I'd suggest taking a look at Drupal, as it does a lot of this type of stuff. Might be able to pick up some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to ask the question "How do I do it?" then it is most likely over your head. Take a look at the stucture of Wordpress' files. That is what helped me out.

I am about to upload my own start at a CMS framework to google code. I'll do it and post the link as soon as they are not in maintenance mode anymore.

Basically the file structure is index.php -> cms-header.php -> (load.php & includes/template-loader.php) -> lots more files.

**[EDIT]** Here is the link [Penguin CMS](http://code.google.com/p/penguin-cms/). It is still **very** much in beta... not even worthy of being called beta, but hopefully you get the idea.